# file regex expansion in bash shell

Tags: regex, bash

I want to view the last lines of a set of files, namely: file9.log, file10.log, file11.log and file12.log

The following expression shows only the last lines of file10 through file12:

```
tail -n 2 file[91][0-2].log
```

How can I specify that [0-2] is optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
tail -n 2 file{9..12}.log
```

This gets expanded to

```
tail -n 2 file9.log file10.log file11.log file12.log
```

Comment: Why can't I upvote and accept at the same time ? Have to wait 5 min before I can accept your answer :).

Comment: I don't know, I think it's to prevent bots upvoting everything.

Answer (score 2):

```
find -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*file(9|1[0-2])\.log' -exec tail -n 2 '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, set extended glob:

```
set extglob
```

Then specify the optional part:

```
tail -n 2 file[91]?([0-2]).log
```

Comment: Technically, this would also match `file90.log`, `file91.log`, and `file92.log` if they exist. Try `file@(9|1[0-2]).log` instead.